# can't install PIP (get-pip.py)

Tags: python, pip

Let's Get Straight to the point. Hello, I Have Python 3.9, and Windows 10 Pro.  I Was installing PIP, but when i type "py get-pip.py", it just puts a blank line and then turns back to normal.

[image: The Image (if you can't picture it, see this image.)]

i tried going to the file myself and seeing what was wrong, there were no problems. to make sure i put "print("PIP HAS BEEN INSTALLED. VERIFY THE INSTALLATION")" (by "verify" it means to test if PIP has been installed.) and LO AND BEHOLD! it doesn't work. How the hell do i fix this?

Comment: Pip should already be on your system. Try `pip3 --version` or `pip --version`. How did you install python? I haven't had a lot of luck on recent versions of Windows 10 except through the Windows store.

Comment: The first step should be to check if the Python interpreter is callable, by typing "python" in cmd/ps. There are multiple ways to install Python on Windows, some of them don't even require to have your environment variable PATH point to the Python interpreter & scripts directory (if you use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win) for example).

Comment: @MrFuppes when I type "Python" in CMD, it just opens up microsoft store and there is "python 3.8" which microsoft store is showing, ofc i didn't download it, i already have 3.9.

Comment: @JaredSmith Well, i can confirm my PC is 100% New since i switched the CPU only like, 10-50 Days ago, because windows 7 always had a problem booting up, i wanted to upgrade, i upgraded like 5-30 days ago, so there shouldn't be any problems in windows. ofcourse, Windows 10 almost always gets a problem at startup, it's like "KMODE EXCEPTION NOT HANDLED" or "PAGE FAULT IN NON-PAGED AREA" or a stop similar to the 1st one but other than that, it's cool. (sorry for long comment.) (also that :( frowny face doesn't help, Microsoft.)

Comment: rest assured that this is not an issue of your PC or Windows. Check your environment variable PATH. It should contain the directory where you installed Python 3.9 and its Scripts folder (this is where pip lives...). The default install path on Windows should be "C:\Users\\[your_username]\AppData\Local\Programs\".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pip comes by default with installing Python. Have you added Python to your PATH? Or did you accidently uncheck pip installation? I would try reinstalling Python and make sure you have checked everything correctly. You can verify if you have pip installed by simply typing "pip" into the console.

Comment: Oh! Yes! I Did uncheck PIP installation since i didn't knew what it was and i unchecked at Python to PATH, Thanks!

Comment: @mafnankhattak260: you don't have to go through the whole installation of Python again - post-installing pip with the `get-pip.py` script is perfectly fine.